# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Spark DAG with more stages

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory-management, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have a spark job which runs sql joins.

I visualized the DAG and it creates +5 stages every join . Anyhow after the stage where DAG has around 40 stages, the next step always fails with exception i.e after 8 iterations with 5 stages each.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.hugeCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:161)
>     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.newCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:155)
>     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
>     at
>   java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
>     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)   at
>   java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)    at
>   scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:125)     at
>   scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:95)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2392)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2420)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2419)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2801)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2419)    at
>   com.samsung.cloud.mopay.linking.controller.PostNotificLinkController.linkPostNotific(PostNotificLinkController.java:51)
>     at
>   com.samsung.cloud.mopay.linking.txn.TxnLinking.performTxnLinking(TxnLinking.java:26)
>     at
>   com.samsung.cloud.mopay.linking.Linking.processData(Linking.java:199)
>     at com.samsung.cloud.mopay.linking.Linking.main(Linking.java:72)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I am running spark with

```
--conf spark.driver.memory=30g 
--conf spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=15g
--conf spark.executor.memory=10g
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=6g
--conf spark.executor.cores=5
```

3 instances per node (r3.2xlarge) = >12 executor instances

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to persist the data after a few stages. This will start a new execution plan and will not add to the existing plan making it bigger and bigger and run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The root issue is you are applying many transformations on a dataframe all along and not persisting or destroying its lineage.

Why Lineage/DAG?
Spark uses these lineages to ensure its fault-tolerant. There is a trade-off between how much fault-tolerance do you need depending on the application and the Dataframe to be built.

Ways to avoid it:

After a few expensive transformations you can:

1. Persist in to HDFS (Simply write to parquet)
2. Checkpointing after few stages (Inbuilt persisting by spark core)
3. Create a new data frame from scratch of the existing ones. (Gets rid of the lineages)

Answer (score -1):

I can give you a couple ideas. Without knowing more about your datasets (size and basic statistics) and basic spark configs (parallelism)... these are just my top guesses:

How big are your datasets, how big are your partitions / how many partitions? Try to use more/smaller partitions - what's the default spark.default.parallelism / spark.sql.shuffle.partitions?

Maybe there's a hot spot in your dataset? Are there keys with a lot of records in any of the joined datasets? You need to analyze your data and collect some stats on all operands involved and top frequent join keys in each (the join may multiply your data).

If you can provide more details then I'll give you more educated guesses.

Comment: This has not much to do with amount of data or parallelism. Looks like the query execution plan created is too big to fit into memory.

Comment: You're right, my bad, I didn't pay attention to the whole stack trace. Well... it the first time I see that, you must be doing a lot of things... I guess in that case I would try to break the lineage by splitting the processing in multiple steps, checkpointing intermediate datasets, etc.